# How to decrease the use of .then in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

First of all, sorry for typing mistakes, Portuguese is my main language but im trying.

I'm creating a timer, which updates every 500ms and checks if the number is a multiple of 30, it's a test code and for now only has this function. The problem is that I'm using too much .then and the code is getting illegible.

The code:

```js
function startLiveUpdate() {
  const timerURL = 'http://localhost:8000/jsons/data.json';

  setInterval(function() {
    fetch(timerURL).then(function(response) {
      return response.json();
    }).then(function(data) {
      var gameTime = data.gameTime;
      document.getElementById("timer").textContent = gameTime;
      return gameTime;
    }).catch(function(error) {
      console.log(error);
    }).then(function(gameTime) {
      var timings = [
        10,
        20,
        30,
        40,
        60,
        70,
        80,
        90
      ]
      for (time of timings) {
        if (gameTime < time) {
          var nextTime = time;
          if (nextTime % 30 == 0) {
            document.getElementById("next").textContent = nextTime + ' MULTIPLO';
            document.getElementById("cron").textContent = nextTime - gameTime;
            console.log(nextTime);
          } else {
            document.getElementById("next").textContent = nextTime;
            document.getElementById("cron").textContent = nextTime - gameTime;
            console.log(nextTime);
          }

          break;
        }

      }
    });
  }, 1000);
}
```

I wanted to know if there's any way to leave small functions, for example one that takes the data, one that reads and understands it and another that checks if it's a multiple of 30. All the ways I've tried, either they don't update every 500ms or they just don't work

Thanks!

Comment: @BARNOWL depends if OP has a build step. Native support for async/await is pretty shit, doesn't work in IE for example (if OP needs to support it ofc)

Comment: I count three uses of `.then()` and wouldn't consider that _"too many"_. You could of course combine the second and third ones

Comment: Why do you have that `.catch(…)` in the middle of your promise chain?

Comment: @Phiter `fetch` has no IE support either. The browser compatibility of `fetch` and `async / await` is about the same

Comment: @Phil yeah in this case, I think OP is safe with `async/await`, but fetch has polyfills, `async/await` doesn't, so it can be a small risk.

Comment: @BARNOWL this isn't _"callback hell"_ since promises are chainable. Callback hell is when you need to use several APIs supporting the `method(...args, (err, result) => {...})` format

Comment: @Phil Thank you both for correcting me, i learned something new :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your current code can be refactored a bit to be more readable. You can use `async/await` but you'll have reduced browser support, unless you don't care for IE.

```js
function getData() {
  const timerURL = 'http://localhost:8000/jsons/data.json';
  return fetch(timerURL).then(function(response) {
    return response.json();
  }).then(function(data) {
    var gameTime = data.gameTime;
    return gameTime;
  })
}

function startLiveUpdate() {
  

  setInterval(function() {
    getData().then(function(gameTime) {
      document.getElementById("timer").textContent = gameTime;
      var timings = [
        10,
        20,
        30,
        40,
        60,
        70,
        80,
        90
      ]
      for (time of timings) {
        if (gameTime < time) {
          var nextTime = time;
          if (nextTime % 30 == 0) {
            document.getElementById("next").textContent = nextTime + ' MULTIPLO';
            document.getElementById("cron").textContent = nextTime - gameTime;
            console.log(nextTime);
          } else {
            document.getElementById("next").textContent = nextTime;
            document.getElementById("cron").textContent = nextTime - gameTime;
            console.log(nextTime);
          }

          break;
        }

      }
    });
  }, 1000);
}
```

Of course if you decide to use `async/await`, your code can look much better:

```js
const getData = async () => {
  const timerURL = 'http://localhost:8000/jsons/data.json';
  const response = await fetch(timerURL);
  const { gameTime } = await response.json();
  return gameTime;
}

function startLiveUpdate() {
  setInterval(async () => {
    let gameTime = null;
    try {
      gameTime = await getData();
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error);
      return;
    }

    document.getElementById("timer").textContent = gameTime;
    var timings = [
      10,
      20,
      30,
      40,
      60,
      70,
      80,
      90
    ]
    for (time of timings) {
      if (gameTime < time) {
        var nextTime = time;
        if (nextTime % 30 == 0) {
          document.getElementById("next").textContent = nextTime + ' MULTIPLO';
          document.getElementById("cron").textContent = nextTime - gameTime;
          console.log(nextTime);
        } else {
          document.getElementById("next").textContent = nextTime;
          document.getElementById("cron").textContent = nextTime - gameTime;
          console.log(nextTime);
        }

        break;
      }

    }
  }, 1000);
}
```

Comment: Godammit I forgot `.then` itself returns a Promise. I'll fix my answer.

Comment: Throw in a check for `response.ok` and this might even handle request errors

Comment: Thank you so much! Now I can see ways to proceed, I will implement right now

Answer (score 3):

You'd be looking for [Async/await](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Asynchronous/Async_await)! Use it with promises instead of `.then`, and it'll make things much more tidy!

Comment: It won't make it that *much* more tidy in the OP's concrete example though. It doesn't even decrease nesting level if you account for the `try` block.

Comment: You do raise a valid point when you consider it from an indentation point of view, but utilising `async`/`await` will reduce the lines, as well as the brackets within this code snippet, which arguably aids OP in making their code more legible, as requested.

Comment: Some parenthesis can be avoided by using arrow syntax instead of `function` expressions. And it doesn't even reduce lines in this example - see my answer for the two version next to each other. (I do agree that legibility is increased, and in the long run it definitely helps and leads to more concise code)

Answer (score 2):

As already mentioned there are not so many `.then` there are only 3 and as it was also mentioned you can combine the second and third. You could also modulate your logic code to functions, the last one in particular can be simplified a lot since it should only concatenate a text if the condition is met.

Please take a look to this example

```
function startLiveUpdate() {
  const timerURL = "http://localhost:8000/jsons/data.json";

  setInterval(() => {
    fetch(timerURL)
      .then((response) => response.json())
      .then((data) => {
        setTimer(data.gameTime);

        check(data.gameTime);
      })
      .catch(function (error) {
        console.log(error);
      });
  }, 1000);
}

function setTimer(gameTime) {
  document.getElementById("timer").textContent = data.gameTime;
}

function check(gameTime) {
  var timings = [10, 20, 30, 40, 60, 70, 80, 90];

  for (time of timings) {
    if (gameTime < time) {
      const suffix = time % 30 === 0 ? " MULTIPLO" : "";

      document.getElementById("next").textContent = time + suffix;
      document.getElementById("cron").textContent = time - gameTime;

      break;
    }
  }
}
```

If this is not enough try async and await [Making asynchronous programming easier with async and await](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Asynchronous/Async_await)

Answer (score 1):

A first step would be some cleanup, moving the `catch` error handler to the end, joining the two synchronous `then` into one and using arrow functions:

```
function startLiveUpdate() {
  const timerURL = 'http://localhost:8000/jsons/data.json';

  setInterval(() => {
    fetch(timerURL).then(response =>
      response.json();
    ).then(data => {
      var gameTime = data.gameTime;
      document.getElementById("timer").textContent = gameTime;
      var timings = [10, 20, 30, 40, 60, 70, 80, 90];
      for (var nextTime of timings) {
        if (gameTime < nextTime) {
          if (nextTime % 30 == 0) {
            document.getElementById("next").textContent = nextTime + ' MULTIPLO';
          } else {
            document.getElementById("next").textContent = nextTime;
          }
          document.getElementById("cron").textContent = nextTime - gameTime;
          console.log(nextTime);
          break;
        }
      }
    }).catch(console.log);
  }, 1000);
}
```

You can also use `async`/`await` instead of `.then()` syntax:

```
function startLiveUpdate() {
  const timerURL = 'http://localhost:8000/jsons/data.json';

  setInterval(async () => {
    try {
      var response = await fetch(timerURL)
      var data = await response.json();
      var gameTime = data.gameTime;
      document.getElementById("timer").textContent = gameTime;
      var timings = [10, 20, 30, 40, 60, 70, 80, 90];
      for (var nextTime of timings) {
        if (gameTime < nextTime) {
          if (nextTime % 30 == 0) {
            document.getElementById("next").textContent = nextTime + ' MULTIPLO';
          } else {
            document.getElementById("next").textContent = nextTime;
          }
          document.getElementById("cron").textContent = nextTime - gameTime;
          console.log(nextTime);
          break;
        }
      }
    } catch(err) {
      console.log(err);
    }
  }, 1000);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need most of your `then()`s

```
// this doesn't need to be inline
// smaller chunks of code are easier to worry about. 
function setGameTime(data) {
  const gameTime = data.gameTime;
  document.getElementById("timer").textContent = gameTime;

  // condensed the two functions into one

  if (gameTime < 90) {
    const timings = [10, 20, 30, 40, 60, 70, 80, 90];
    const nextTime = timings.find(time => gameTime < time);
    // you could even compute `nextTime` as `10*Math.ceil(gameTime/10)`

    const suffix = time % 30 ? '' : ' MULTIPLO';
    document.getElementById("next").textContent = nextTime + suffix;
    document.getElementById("cron").textContent = nextTime - gameTime;
    console.log(nextTime);
  }
}

function startLiveUpdate() {
  const timerURL = 'http://localhost:8000/jsons/data.json';

  setInterval(function () {
    fetch(timerURL)
    // these are the two `then`s you can't avoid:
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(
      setGameTime,
      console.log
    );
  }, 1000);
}
```

And since I'm always annoyed, about that `.then(response => response.json())` I usually extend `fetch()` like this:

```
/**
 * shorthands: fetch.json(input, ?init) 
 * for         fetch(input, ?init).then(response => response.json())
 */
["arrayBuffer","blob","formData","json","text"].forEach(method => {
  const handler = response => response[method]();
  fetch[method] = (input, init=void 0) => fetch(input, init).then(handler);
});
```

Answer (score -1):

I think ES6 could help you to clean your code!

```
  function startLiveUpdate() {
  const timerURL = "http://localhost:8000/jsons/data.json";

  setInterval(() => {
    fetch(timerURL)
      .then((response) => response.json())
      .then((data) => {
        var gameTime = data.gameTime;
        document.getElementById("timer").textContent = gameTime;
        return gameTime;
      })
      .then((gameTime) => {
        var timings = [10, 20, 30, 40, 60, 70, 80, 90];
        for (time of timings) {
          if (gameTime < time) {
            var nextTime = time;
            if (nextTime % 30 == 0) {
              document.getElementById("next").textContent =
                nextTime + " MULTIPLO";
              document.getElementById("cron").textContent = nextTime - gameTime;
              console.log(nextTime);
            } else {
              document.getElementById("next").textContent = nextTime;
              document.getElementById("cron").textContent = nextTime - gameTime;
              console.log(nextTime);
            }
            break;
          }
        }
      })
      .catch((error) => console.log(error));
  }, 1000);
}
```